# Using #define to define and #if defined to see if it is defined

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I am trying to define something. If it is defined I want to do something, else I want to do something different.

```
#define PARSE_STRING
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
#if defined (PARSE_STING)
    /* run code for parsing the strings */
#else
    /* run code that doesn't parse the strings
    }
#endif
```

When I try the above code in my function, I seem to get other errors else where in my code. However, if I comment out the `#define PARSE_STRING` it compiles ok. I am just wondering do I need the `#define PARSE_STRING`?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

====== EDIT with updated solution

Could it be better to do it this way, instead?

```
#define PARSE_STRING
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
#if defined (PARSE_STRING)
    /* run code for parsing the strings */
#elif defined (NO_PARSE_STRING)
    /* run code that doesn't parse the strings
#endif
    }
```

Comment: I edited my code when I pasted it. That is just a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your spelling mitsake will sting you sooner or later: `#if defined(PARSE_STING)` should presumably be `#if defined(PARSE_STRING)`.

Comment: RE: the edit:  no, it's not better that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've mixed up the interleaving of the preprocessing directives with the start and end of the function body:

```
}
#endif
```

Should probably be

```
#endif
}
```

Comment: You are correct. The #endif was out of the scope of the for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because if it is defined, you're going to not have the closing `}` which will be a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You've included the ending bracket for the for loop in one of the conditionals

```
#else
  }
#endif
```

Should be

```
#else
   //Stuff
#endif
}
```